# How to handle ECS container agent docker container logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I am using aws batch with ECS.

ECS tasks can be configured in task definition to use awslogs logDriver and send the logs to cloudwatch, which prevent them taking up space in EC2 instance. But the ECS container agent itself also lives in a docker container and all the docker container logs for it are store in EC2 instance, which fill up the memory very quickly. Is there anyway to set up logDriver for ECS container agent itself?

Also ECS agent stores logs in /var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log.timestamp, which also take up a lot of space. Any idea how to redirect them to cloudwatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have small script in `UserData` (as part of LaunchConfiguration) to install `awslogs` and configure for the same. Please find below the sample snippet.

```
        # Install awslogs and the jq JSON parser
        yum install -y awslogs jq

        # Inject the CloudWatch Logs configuration file contents
        cat > /etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf <<- ''EOF''
        [general]
        state_file = /var/lib/awslogs/agent-state

        [/var/log/dmesg]
        file = /var/log/dmesg
        log_group_name = ${EnvName}-${EnvNumber}#ecs#dmesg
        log_stream_name = {cluster}/{container_instance_id}

        [/var/log/messages]
        file = /var/log/messages
        log_group_name = ${EnvName}-${EnvNumber}#ecs#messages
        log_stream_name = {cluster}/{container_instance_id}

        datetime_format = %b %d %H:%M:%S

        [/var/log/docker]
        file = /var/log/docker
        log_group_name = ${EnvName}-${EnvNumber}#ecs#docker
        log_stream_name = {cluster}/{container_instance_id}
        datetime_format = %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f

        [/var/log/ecs/ecs-init.log]
        file = /var/log/ecs/ecs-init.log.*
        log_group_name = ${EnvName}-${EnvNumber}#ecs#ecs-init.log
        log_stream_name = {cluster}/{container_instance_id}
        datetime_format = %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ

        [/var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log]
        file = /var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log.*
        log_group_name = ${EnvName}-${EnvNumber}#ecs#ecs-agent.log
        log_stream_name = {cluster}/{container_instance_id}
        datetime_format = %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ
```